# How do I split a new line(\n) via a delimiter?

Tags: r, newline

I have a dataframe. and I want to add a newline "\n" with the words "?" or "①" as delimiters. ex) "?" -> "?\n" Typing "?\n" seems to cause a syntax error.

I have a dataframe :

```
sample : 
aa <- data.frame(c('[1] aaaaa? ① bbbbb ② ccccc','[2] ccccc ① fffff  ② ggggg'))


[1] aaaaa ① bbbbb ② ccccc
[2] ccccc ① fffff ② ggggg
```

result :

```
[1] aaaaaa? \n
① bbbbb \n
② ccccc
[2] cccccccc? \n
① fffff \n
② ggggg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `cat()` instead of `print()` when you print to the console. For example:

```
aa <- data.frame(text = c('[1] aaaaa?\n① bbbbb\n② ccccc\n','[2] ccccc\n① fffff\n② ggggg\n'))
print(aa)
#                             text
# 1 [1] aaaaa?\n① bbbbb\n② ccccc\n
# 2  [2] ccccc\n① fffff\n② ggggg\n

cat(unlist(aa), sep="")
# [1] aaaaa?
# ① bbbbb
# ② ccccc
# [2] ccccc
# ① fffff
# ② ggggg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to programmatically add the new lines, you can use `gsub`:

```
result = gsub(pattern = "([①②])" ,
     replacement = "\n\\1", x = aa[[1]])

result
# [1] 1] "[1] aaaaa? \n① bbbbb \n② ccccc" "[2] ccccc \n① fffff  \n② ggggg"
cat(result, sep = "\n")
# [1] aaaaa? 
# ① bbbbb 
# ② ccccc
# [2] ccccc 
# ① fffff  
# ② ggggg
```

As dcarlson explains, in the R console `print` will print the `\n` characters, `cat` will interpret them as line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

separate_rows(aa, text, sep = "\n")
```

```
  text        
  <chr>       
1 "[1] aaaaa?"
2 "<U+2460> bbbbb"   
3 "<U+2461> ccccc"   
4 ""          
5 "[2] ccccc" 
6 "<U+2460> fffff"   
7 "<U+2461> ggggg"
```